# Creating a hash during a loop with strange behavior

Tags: ruby

this is my code, I try creating a hash with header as key and arrays of hashs with values, but result don't keep data after loop, in contrast result[key] works normaly.

```
  def programacao
    result = Hash.new([])
    header = nil
    csv_each_for(file_to('programacao/9')).each do |row|
      next if row[0].nil?

      if row[0].start_with?('#')
        header = row[0]
        next
      end
      # puts "HEADER #{header} / ROW: #{row[0]}"
      result[header] << ({
                            horario: row[0],
                            evento: row[1],
                            tema: row[2],
                            palestante: row[3],
                            instituicao: row[4],
                            local: row[5]
      })
      binding.pry
    end
    result
  end
```

**FIRST ITERATION:**

```
[1] pry(#<Programacao>)> result
=> {}
```

but result[reader]

```
[3] pry(#<Programacao>)> result[header]
=> [{:horario=>"09:00 - 9:50",
  :evento=>"Palestra",
  :tema=>"Reforma da Previdência",
  :palestante=>"Dr. Álvaro Mattos Cunha Neto",
  :instituicao=>"Advogado - Presidente da Comissão de Direito Previdenciário",
  :local=>"OAB"}]
```

**SECOND ITERATION:**

```
[1] pry(#<Programacao>)> result
=> {}
```

Header steel works normaly

```
[2] pry(#<Programacao>)> result[header]
=> [{:horario=>"09:00 - 9:50",
  :evento=>"Palestra",
  :tema=>"Reforma da Previdência",
  :palestante=>"Dr. Álvaro Mattos Cunha Neto",
  :instituicao=>"Advogado - Presidente da Comissão de Direito Previdenciário",
  :local=>"OAB"},
 {:horario=>"9:00 -10:00", :evento=>"Solenidade de abertura do Estande", :tema=>nil, :palestante=>"Direção/Coordenações", :instituicao=>nil, :local=>"Faculdade Católica do Tocantins"}]
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: can you share your csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, because you have not provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (What is `csv_each_for`? What is `file_to`? What is your input CSV? If providing all of this information is unnecessary, then can you provide a *minimal* example?)

However, I believe the crux of your problem is in this line:

```
result = Hash.new([])
```

Instead, you should use:

```
result = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
```

This is because, as mentioned in [the ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-new), you need to create a **new** default object each time.

This is a [common gotcha](https://makandracards.com/david-alejandro/44508-gotcha-on-default-value-for-array-and-shovel-method). It was because of this mistake that you were seeing the bizarre behaviour, where `result == {}` but `result[something] == [{:horario=>"09:00 - 9:50", ...}]`.